# I want to count instances of the same python class with a variable

Tags: python, class, count, counter

```
MAX_ANTS = 100 
x = 0 
def next_id():    
   x += 1    
   return x 
        
class Ant:   
   def __init__(self):
      self.id = next_id()
         
i = 0
while i <= MAX_ANTS:
i = i + 1
Ant(i)
```

Is there any way i can make this code work ?
i want to generate a set amount of Ants (MAX_ANTS)
and then set their id with a variable
**Thanks for any help.**

Comment: You would need `global x` inside `next_id()` - the fact that the function assigns to the variable makes it a local variable, by default.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need most of your code.  You're iterating anyway so you can just assign 'i' as the id, no need for the globals or other function etc.  I also assume you want to do something with the ants later, so put them into a list.

```
MAX_ANTS = 100 
       
class Ant:   
   def __init__(self, id):
      self.id = id
         
ants = []
for i in range(MAX_ANTS):
    ants.append(Ant(i))
```

You could be even more concise with list comprehension.

```
ants = [Ant(i) for i in range(MAX_ANTS)]
```

Comment: thank you im a beginner in python its difficult for me and i didnt knew you could use append() to add an instance of a class i thought it was only with lists
also i dont quite understand what the ants = [] stands for
and i dont really need a list since i will make them move on their own so i will put the code inside the instance

Edit i think the ants = [] sets the list of all the instances of the class (tell me if i'm wrong XD)

Comment: ants = [] creates an empty list.  append adds instances of Ant to that list.  If you don't store them somewhere, you won't be able to do anything with them later.

Comment: but ants.append(Ant(i)) store them to the list right ?

Comment: @Xczmike2428 run the code and see what it does! that's the only way to learn.